# Receiving empty push message after sending GCM Upstream Message

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I've implemented the sending of GCM upstream messages in the same way like it's provided on the android developer site. The XMPP Server also receives the upstream messages and confirms the ACK from GCM.

But for some reason I always get an empty notification on my client, after the ACK was send from XMPP to GCM to confirm the upstream message.

The empty notification only consists of:

```
Bundle[{google.sent_time=1489154979847, google.message_id=0:14dwa91daw806%0d31231dqwdecd}]
```

Why does this message arrive? There is nothing in the doc mentioned about receiving some kind of "ACK" after sending upstream messages. It confuses me that this message is completely empty.

Comment: You may refer with this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36767947/android-notification-push-empty-using-gcm-and-java-with-json-message).

Comment: @abielita Unfortunately, it seems that it's a different problem. I'm actually receiving my own push notifications (with content, etc.), which are sent from the server. The problem is, that I get the unexpected empty message due to the ACK sent from my server to GCM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was a typo on the server, instead 'message_type' 'messg_type' was used. Therefore, the ACK which was sent from server to GCM was not recognized as a ACK and the problem appeared.